# MeteorJS - List item Not updating after implementing publish / subscribe and methods / calls

Tags: meteor, methods, publish, subscribe

Ok so this is a little weird...

I got these methods on server side ...

```
Meteor.publish('todos', function () {
return Todos.find({userId: this.userId},{sort:{createdAt:-1}});
});

Meteor.methods({
    editTodo: function(todoId) {
        Todos.update(todoId, {$set: {checked: !this.checked}});
    }
});
```

And here is the invocation on client side ....

```
Template.list.helpers({
    todos: function(){
        Meteor.subscribe('todos');
        return Todos.find({});
    }
});
Template.list.events({
    "click .toggle-check": function(){
        Meteor.call('editTodo',this._id);
    }});
```

The problem is that when the click on ".toggle-check" occurs ... the 'checked' boolean is triggered on but never comes off .... is this.checked (in {checked: !this.checked}) not referring to field immediately read from the collection?
Or maybe I am implementing something wrong when subscribing to the data?

Please help!

Comment: In your method, does "this.checked" resolve to the right thing? That looks weird.

Comment: it is getting rendered on the view because I am rendering the checked state into a checkbox what seems to be happening (after some more investigation) is that the update is not occurring.  What is being missed out from this is that i have a full CRUD here working SELECT , INSERT , DELETE all work fine UPDATE seems not to work properly.  

Upon further scrutiny I noticed that when i hit the update button , I retrieved and showed the row in the console (via server-side) , checked is always coming set to true but never goes false. So !this.checked is not working essentially. Also no allow/deny!

Comment: yes, I'm saying that "this" is probably not what you think in that context. At least, i've never seen it used like that. i would proceed with debugging the use of "this".

Comment: just for the record ... 'this' does indeed refer to the checked value coming from the record itself.

Comment: ok cool. i've never seen that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue relates to the registration of the subscription as you suggested - more specifically that your `Meteor.subscribe()` is being called from within a `Template.helpers` function.

Try moving your subscription to an earlier page or template event such as `Template.body.onCreated()` or `Template.list.onCreated()` (depending on your requirements).

There is a good example in the Meteor documentation: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe (see section 10.3).

Comment: Right now I'm not in front of a PC but will go for your suggestion and keep you posted .  So you think that its due to latency? If i relocate all subscriptions to Meteor.startup()   do you think that it would resolve the issue?

Comment: I believe that's correct (for both those questions :)  In the end, I relocated my `Meteor.subscribe()` calls to within `Template.body.onRendered(function() {})` in `\imports\startup\client\index.js` and all works very smoothly now

Comment: though the subscribe should not be in the helper (i would move it to the onCreated()), i don't think that's the issue. in that helper, the find() should still be reactive. there's just no need to keep hitting that subscribe every time Blaze decides to call that helper. once is sufficient.